# One Large SVN Merge vs Several Small Merges - Timesout!

Tags: svn, merge, timeout

I'm currently merging my trunk into a different branch. There have been close to 3000 commits in between. The SVN repo resides on a remote server and when I do the merge on the full set of revisions SVN fails saying the connection to the SVN server timed out. Thinking there was just too much merge action, I tried to do smaller merges, between the first 200 commits, which didn't timeout -- so then I proceeded to keep merging in increments of 200.

Is this going to cause problems? (not merging a full set of revisions?)

Is there a way to keep SVN from timing out when merging a huge set of changes?

UPDATE: Error Message

```
svn: REPORT of '/repos/somerepo/with/code': timed out waiting for server (http://my.svn.server.com)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like a client side timeout.  Depends on your client but take a look at your `[home directory]/.subversion/servers` file for a field named `http-timeout` in the `[global]` section.

GUI tools usually have an option for this and sometimes mis-label it as a proxy related setting even though all timeouts are global (e.g. IntelliJ)

Comment: That worked. I had it set to 3 seconds, so when I tried removing it, it still timed out. So then I added an even higher value (180) and it finished.

Comment: I had this issue when I was trying to pull down all the tags, and not just the trunk that I was working from.

Comment: I had this issue due to a pre-commit hook that we had set up with our repository, disabling the hook made my huge merge commits to go lightning fast!